# How to retrieve EXIF information of an ActiveStorage image in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, exif

I am using Rails 6.0 with ActiveStorage and AWS storage.
I would like to know how to retrieve EXIF information (only latitude and longitude) of an image.

I have a form to upload the image. What's the best process to get this EXIF information :  Just after validations or after create ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a user with avatar maybe ou have a class like that

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

To get a exif info you can run this:

```
user = User.find 1
MiniMagick::Image.open(user.avatar).exif
```

A gem that you need:

```
gem "mini_magick"
```

More about [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick)

Comment: Thanks @thiaguerd ;)
It work fine 
    `MiniMagick::Image.open(user.avatar).exif` return the exif hash :

```{"ApertureValue"=>"153/100",
 "BrightnessValue"=>"274/100",
...
...
 "GPSLatitude"=>"44/1, 36/1, 183884/10000",
 "GPSLatitudeRef"=>"N",
}```

but 

`MiniMagick::Image.open(user.avatar).exif.[:GPSLatitude]` return nil

Comment: @Ben you ware welcome. Try ```exif["GPSLatitude"]```